# How to mov 16-bit register to an 8-bit register in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers

Pardon me if it has been asked already, I was able to find how to move a value from 8-bit register to a 16-bit register using movsx, but not able to find an instruction that does the opposite.
I noticed that cmov instructions don't work with 8-bit registers, so I'm trying to move the 8-bit register to a 16-bit, do cmov operation with that 16-bit register, then move the value in that 16-bit register back into the 8-bit register. So for the last part, does x86 ISA have an instruction that can move a value from a 16-bit register to a 8-bit register?
If it doesn't, can you suggest a work around for it?

Comment: Use the 8 bit partial register. E.g. `al`, `bl`, etc. Or just use the full register and don't move stuff around.

Comment: If you don't want all 16 bits, don't read them in the first place.  It would be silly for x86 to have an instruction that read a 16-bit source but discarded some of those bits, you can just read an 8-bit part of a register in the first place.  Like Jester said, `cmovle eax, ecx` or whatever will write the whole EAX, including AL.

Comment: @Jester I should have explained it better, sorry about that. My problem with that approach is that I'm inserting these instructions as inline assembly and have references in the inline assembly instructions that substitutes in variables. So right now I'm checking the type of the variable, and depending on the type size I change the instruction type and the second register (like if it's int, I use movl and eax register). Is there a way where I can force the inline assembly instruction to use 16-bit or 32-bit register despite what the size of the variable is?

Comment: (Adding to the last comment) Since the compiler inserts the register name at the time of compilation, I don't know what register will be used. So is there a way I can force the variable to be stored in a specific register?

Comment: Yes, in gcc inline asm you can use constraints and register variables and size modifiers. But the compiler probably can generate better code than you can, so why not just let it do so from C?

Comment: I am manually inserting them to force some conversions for which I haven't found a reliable way to enforce compiler to retain those conversions in every case :( But thanks for the clarification, I'll look into register variable and constrains that I can use

Comment: @Jester One more question, do you know of a way where I can force the variable to be in a specific register when it's being loaded that doesn't require me to create a register variable? Is there a constrain I can specify to enforce that?

Comment: Yes, there are register constraints for a subset of the registers. Consult the gcc manual (assuming you use gcc).